# How to install weak cipher to connect to legacy SSH servers?

Tags: linux, ssh

While we are upgrading our clusters, we noticed there are some legacy nodes that use very old version of `openssh`. Our current SSH clients cannot talk to them. How do we temporary install weak cipher to upgrade those nodes?

Here are the command logs

```
[~] ssh username@node.legacy
Unable to negotiate with 10.10.10.10 port 22: no matching cipher found. Their offer: arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
```

Supported ciphers

```
[~] ssh -Q cipher
3des-cbc
aes128-cbc
aes192-cbc
aes256-cbc
rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
aes128-ctr
aes192-ctr
aes256-ctr
aes128-gcm@openssh.com
aes256-gcm@openssh.com
chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
```

We have tried the following and it's not working.

```
[~] ssh -vv -c arcfour username@node.legacy
Unknown cipher type 'arcfour'
```

Comment: install an old version of OpenSSH as `icky-old-ssh` somewhere and then use that until the old nodes can be put out to pasture?

Comment: A host-based .ssh/config file could help, too — so you’re only using insecure ciphers where you need to

Comment: True, Stephen — just trying to limit the damage, in case the ssh default configuration does not include the insecure  ciphers, they do not need to be added globally

Comment: Yeah I realised that with your extended comment (which is why I deleted my comment). I agree an icky-old-SSH would be safer with a `.ssh/config` set up correctly.